# High Level Function Confusion with Lambda/LINQ expressions in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linqpad

Unsure how to describe this question so the title might be wrong.

Am reading over some code examples and am confused over the following return function:

```
Func<Func<int , bool>, Func<int , int>, Func<int , int>> Loop = null ;
Loop = (c , f ) => n => c(n) ? Loop(c , f ) ( f (n)): n;
Func<int , int> w = Loop(n => n < 10 , n => n + 2); 
var r = w(2); 
var s = w(3);
Console . WriteLine ("{0} {1}" , r , s );
```

I understand that this function is returning the Loop when c(n) evaluates to true, but I don't understand how Loop(c,f) (f(n)) evaluates - are they both being passed back into Loop? I have tried running dumps in Linqpad and I just don't get how that bit is running.

Any help would be appreciated, understand this is probably a dumb question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to try to understand it is start small: have basic loop 1-10 with +1 increment.

```
 Func<int,int> basicLoop = null;
 basicLoop = n => n < 10 ? basicLoop(n+1) : n;
```

That's pretty simple - `basicLoop` is function that based on parameter `n` returns `n` (for n >= 10) or calls itself with incremented parameter. So `basicLoop(8)` is computed as:

- `basicLoop(8)` 8 < 10, so calls `basicLoop(8+1)` to get result
- `basicLoop(9)` 9 < 10, so calls `basicLoop(9+1)` to get result
- `basicLoop(10)` 10 == 10, so returns `n` which is 10.
- `basicLoop(9)` got result 10 (from `basicLoop(10)`) and returns it
- `basicLoop(8)` got result 10 (from `basicLoop(9)`)and returns it

Now we want to pass condition as parameter to the loop. That means our "loop" `Func` will need to pass that condition around on every iteration:

Type of that condition is clearly (similar to `n<10`) - `Func<int, bool>`. So now we have something that takes `Func<int,bool>` as argument and returns same value as our original `basicLoop`. Hence it will be `Func` of one argument and one result:

```
Func<Func<int, bool>, Func<int,int>> condLoop = null;
```

`condLoop` is function of one argument - so when defining we take argument: `condLoop = (condition) => ...`.

We need to replace condition in our original `basicLoop`: `n => n < 10 ? ...`  becomes `n => condition(n) ? ...`.

The last part is replacing `basicLoop(n+1)` - we have `condLoop` function that returns equivalent of `basicLoop` when you pass condition to it. Fortunately our condition does not change between iterations and we already have it - `condLoop(condition)` is equivalent of `basicLoop`. Getting it all together:

```
condLoop = (condition) =>
   n => condition(n) ? 
      condLoop(condition) (n + 1) :
      n;
```

Tracing through calls `condLoop(x => x < 5)(4)`

- `condLoop(x => x < 5)(4)` - condition is `x => x < 5`, n = 4 so when `condition(4)` is called x = 4, 4 < 5 is true - calling `condLoop` with same condition and increased n - `condLoop(x => x < 5)(4 + 1)` to get result
- `condLoop(x => x < 5)(5)` - condition is `x => x < 5`, n = 5 so when `condition(5)` is called x = 5, 5 < 5  is false - returning `n` which is 5
- back to `condLoop(x => x < 5)(4)` - returning 5 as result of `condLoop(x => x < 5)(5)`

With similar logic adding function that increments value - on every iteration now you need to pass `condition` and `increment` function (`c` and `f` in original post).

Comment: Ah! So the syntax Loop(c, f)(f(n)) is calling (f(n)) as the condition on which to recall Loop(c,f)? I'm just struggling with how that syntax operates I think.

Comment: I'd not call it "condition on which recall Loop" - also maybe you just used "condition" as "value for next iteration"... `Loop(c, f)` returns function of one argument similar to `basicLoop` one. `f(n)` is just call to `f` function .... combined - `Loop(c,f) (f(n))` is call `Loop(c, f)` with result of `f(n)`... or in other words  - what `n` should be on next iteration of the loop...

Comment: You may try to pass functions that log each invocation like condition `n => {Console.WriteLine("Condition {0}", n);return n < 10;}` and stare at output for some time...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the syntax of the f(n)(n) - very silly overlook on my part. I do understand the iteration though, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

C#'s anonymous delegate declaration syntax leads to confusion, so I'm going to rewrite it in F#'s function type syntax.

```
(int -> bool) -> (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
```

So this is a function that takes two functions and returns a function. The first function it accepts is a predicate, the second is likely a map, and finally it returns a function that accepts an int to return an int.

```
Loop = (c , f ) => n => c(n) ? Loop(c , f ) ( f (n)): n;
```

The implementation of the above signature. It takes two parameters, as expected, as c and f. We expect it to return a function, and here it is:

```
n => c(n) ? Loop(c,f) (f (n)) : n;
```

I can imagine the Loop(c,f) (f (n)) part is throwing you the most. The result of calling Loop is a function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. n is an integer, and f is a function that takes an integer and returns an integer. In the terms of `w` it increments that integer by 2. So, given an n of 2, as in the first example, you would pass the result of f(n), 2 + 2, as a new n. So long as c(n) resolves true, you will continue to iterate, with n increasing by 2 each time until greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: That is really helpful, but I think I'm just missing something maybe with the syntax.
With Loop (c,f) (f(n)), I don't understand how the Loop ever ceases - shouldn't the (f(n)) have to resolve before recalling Loop(c,f) for the new value to have been changed?

Comment: `f(n)` is just int value... on every iteration it will increase (for f = `x =>x + 2` as in your sample) like 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,... and eventually condition will be false to trigger evaluation of last part of `?:` which stops recursion by returning current value.

Comment: Function `f` in the terms of `w` takes a number and adds 2 to it. Function `c` in the terms of `w` returns true if the number entered is less than 10. `Loop(c,f)` returns `n => c(n) ? Loop(c,f) (f (n)) : n;` You can think of it in steps. The first value entered is 2. 2 < 10, so it passes the check by c(n). f(n) == f(2) == 2 + 2 == 4. Loop(c,f) == `n => c(n) ? Loop(c,f) (f (n)) : n;`. `Loop(c,f) (f (n))` == `Loop(c,f) (4)` == `(n => c(n) ? Loop(c,f) (f(n)) : n) (4)` 4 is less then 10, so the branch goes to `Loop(c,f) (f(4))` which is the same as `Loop(c,f) (6)`. You can keep expanding this out.

Answer (score 1):

"I understand that this function is returning the Loop when c(n) evaluates to true, but I don't understand how Loop(c,f) (f(n)) evaluates" - the function doesn't return `Loop`. The function *is* `Loop` and it returns a `Func<int, int>`.

So, `Loop` is a function that takes two functions as input and returns a third function. It has the signature `Func<Func<int , bool>, Func<int , int>, Func<int , int>>` which show this.

Now, `Loop = null` in the first line so that the when `Loop` is actually defined on the second line it can recursively call itself.

Then, `Loop` is basically a function that returns the function `n => c(n) ? Loop(c, f)(f(n)) : n`. That is `Loop` will return a function that, given an `n` in the future, will return `Loop(c, f)(f(n))` when `c(n)` is `true` and `n` when it is `false`;

`w` is then the return function from `Loop` when with the parameters `n => n < 10` & `n => n + 2`.

So, substituting those in to `Loop` you could define `w` like this:

```
Func<int, int> w = null;
w = n => n < 10 ? w(n + 2) : n;
```

Now that can be re-written as this:

```
int w(int n)
{
    while (n < 10)
    {
        n += 2;
    }
    return n;
}
```

And hopefully that progression is easy to see.