# Search in Doubly Linked List c#

Tags: c#, search, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing an application which is using a doubly linked list. I need to implement search in this list. There is a list of employees with the name, id, department. What I need to do is to find the specified employee by her/his last name. Any ideas, how it's possible to implement?

Comment: Sure: 1. Iterate 2. Compare 3. Return

Comment: Just iterating through the list seems the obvious option. Are you wanting an additional collection more appropriate for that type of searching?

Answer (score 4):

Please do not reinvent the wheel. All classes for this are already in .Net - just initialize [`LinkedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) and use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` to search:

```
  LinkedList<Employee> employees = ....
  var firstWithIdSeven =  employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 7); // assuming id is int
```

Note that if you need frequent search by some subset of parameters using `Dictionary` with custom comparer would be more efficient.

Comment: This list is not from the.Net class, it's self made double linked list with nodes and pointers

Comment: @PLab then implement `IEnumerable<Employee>` on it. (Or consider replacing your current implementation with `LinkedList<T>`).

Comment: @PLab There is no indication in the post that you are looking for someone to write code for you. So I believe recommendation to use built in classes answers your question perfectly fine. In addition it demonstrates that implementation is possible making your job much easier as you no longer need to prove that whether it is indeed possible.

Comment: This is exactly the right advice for real development and for educational purposes if you're learning C#. It's exactly the *wrong* advice for educational purposes if you're learning algorithms but, since there's no indication either way in the question, good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for actual C# code, you should be using the collections that come with the system (such as `LinkedList`).

For educational purposes, the *algorithm* is as follows:

```
def find(lastName):
    set curr to head
    while curr <> null:
        if curr.lastName == lastName:
            return curr
        curr = curr.next
    return null
```

Translating that into C# (or any other procedural language) should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

### Trolling level 7 : recursive lambda

If you are looking for exotic implemetations - check out [High Level Function Confusion with Lambda/LINQ expressions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460623/high-level-function-confusion-with-lambda-linq-expressions-in-c-sharp) that discusses iteration with recursive lambda expression.

So let's say your node is

```
 class Employee
 {
     // code to initialize omitted
     public Employee Next { get;}
     public int Id { get;}
 }
```

Now we can use following recursive lambda (converting to anonymous recursive lambda is exercise for readers)

```
Func<
    Func<Employee, bool>,     // condition to continue iteration
    Func<Employee, Employee>, // "next" function
    Func<Employee, Employee>  // resulting iterator method
    > Loop = null;
Loop = (c , f ) => n => c(n) ? Loop(c , f ) ( f (n)): n;
Func<Employee, Employee> findIdSevenStartingFrom = Loop(
       n => !(n == null || n.Id == 7), // condition to continue search
       n => n.Next );                  // iterator function
```

Now with `findIdSevenStartingFrom` we can pass any element of the list and search to the end to find it by Id.

```
var listHead = new Employee{ Id = 6, Next = new Employee { Id = 7 } };
var item = findIdSevenStartingFrom(listHead);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Double linked node:

```
public class DoubleLinkedList
{
    public Employee Employee {get; set;}
    public DoubleLinkedList Next {get; set;}
    public DoubleLinkedList Prev {get; set;}
}
```

Function to find employee by name in the list:

```
public Employee FindByName(DoubleLinkedList startNode, string name)
{
    var currentNode = startNode;
    while(currentNode != null)
    {
        if(currentNode.Employee.LastName == name) 
        {
            return currentNode.Employee; // Found
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.Next;
    }
    return null; // Not found
}
```